# storage on google cloud

Tags: hadoop, google-bigquery

I have the following use case: a large volume of structured data that I will need to analyze using PySpark. The data is currently in CSV format. I am trying to figure out the best way to store the data on google cloud. My understanding is HDFS won't work because every time the cluster shuts down the HDFS data will disappear so I'll have to convert from CSV to HDFS every time which is time consuming. It seems like the right strategy is to go with BigQuery but I can't determine if BigQuery is persistent or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery is persistent yes, then what you should check is if the SLA is good for you. The SLA, for now, is >= 99.9% data availability monthly.

You can also store in a bucket, in Google Cloud Storage. You have different prices in function of how often you want to access that data: https://cloud.google.com/storage/

Google helps you to choose your storage option, take a look at that page of their doc: https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/

Comment: is reading the data into Spark from CSV equivalent in time as from BigQuery (on say 1TB)? just seeing if storing as Bigquery makes sense in terms of performance

Comment: I have not tested reading from Spark, I use DataFlow instead, but I can tell you that accessing your data in BigQuery becomes almost constant in time if you have enough data. If you have a timestamp, it can be partitioned, which is awesome to reduce your bill. It also has some cache and is very inexpensive.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, BigQuery is persistent, though you can also control the [table expiration time](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#table-expiration). To load the CSV files into BigQuery, you can [create a table from them](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#create-table) by pointing to their location on GCS, assuming that you have copied the files there. There are a variety of third-party connectors that can help with getting your data to GCS, and there is a [Data Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/transfer/) provided by the BigQuery team to help automate transferring your data.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to process your data only with PySpark - you will be better off storing the files in Google Cloud Storage rather than in BigQuery. Even managed Google Cloud's Spark (DataProc) cannot read from BigQuery storage as efficiently as it can from Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: what format would i store it in GCS? i assume CSV is just too uncompressed and slow to read into PySpark?

Comment: IMO, CSV is good enough format, but you can convert your data into any other format that you think will work better with Spark - GCS doesn't care. (With BigQuery storage you don't have any control over data format)

Comment: ok will give straight csv a try. what format would you suggest if not CSV? i'm new to the hadoop and spark ecosystem. parquet?

Comment: It really depends on what kind of processing you need to do. For dome parquet will be better, for others, overhead of converting to parquet will be bigger than any gains. You probably should make this a separate question under spark tag.

Comment: posted under spark, pyspark, parquet tags